# Selecting/deleting text between HTML tags in VsVim

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

In the Visual Studio extension VsVim, is there a way to select, delete or change the text between two HTML or XML tags?

It is possible, for example, to select all text between two speech marks using `vi"` or delete all text between surrounding square brackets using `di]`.

I'd like to apply similar commands to HTML. E.g. `<div>Text to select or delete</div>`.

I think this is the "tag blocks" feature mentioned in the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) but the syntax mentioned doesn't appear to be working in VsVim.

Comment: I've been missing this, too. In VIM I constantly do "vit" for Visual Inner Tab marking. I guess this should be a feature request to @JaredPar.

Comment: I've added a feature request here: https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1446 It would be good to know if there is a work-around for the moment. I'll leave the question open for a bit and if nothing comes up I'll answer that it's not possible in 1.7.0.0.

Comment: The issue I raised was a duplicate of another couple of issues. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab blocks feature allows the use of 't' to indicate that the delimiters should be the surrounding tag blocks. For instance, `vit` with the cursor between on a character between `<span>` tags would go into visual mode and highlight all characters between those tags. E.g.

```
<span>Some text to [s]elect</span>
```

With the block cursor on the 's' as indicated by the []:

- `vit` will select the text `Some text to select`
- `vat` will select the text `<span>Some text to [s]elect</span>`

This has been implemented in version [1.7.1](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/commit/d74012867f98927062f1cf2b76895d44139ea23d) of VsVim and can be installed from as a Visual Studio extension from the gallery as normal: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329

Comment: Looks like this is now in the latest release (as of [1.7.1](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/commit/d74012867f98927062f1cf2b76895d44139ea23d)). Why don't you update and accept your answer?

Comment: Not working for me. Any hints? I have vsvim 1.7.1. The `v` key gets it into visual mode. But then it doesn't respond to the `a` or `t`. Unless I type `v` `a` `t` really fast ... then it will go into insert mode.

Comment: It has been working fine for me with the exception of some nested tags once, where it selected the outer tag not the inner one. Mostly it's fine though. Do you have anything custom in your .vimrc?